# CORS policy - response to preflight request

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors, preflight

I am setting up the CORS policy in my .NET Core 3.1 web app but I am getting an error that says

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.10.100.60/api/api/values/getmyorders?toOrder=false&uId=8c3d745b-78b7-47ed-ac93-310fe61b8daf' from origin 'http://10.10.100.66:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have previously never encountered this preflight error.
Here's what my `Startup` looks like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
         //code shortened for brevity
         services.AddCors();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddProvider(new Log4NetProvider("log4net.config", true));
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I also tried using other CORS methods like the CORS with named policy and middleware as well as the default policy but I still get the same preflight error. Any suggestion on how do I proceed?

Comment: Are you by any chance using identity server 4? do you have a authentication with open id connect?

Comment: Just a thought, could it be because of app.UseHttpsRedirection(), client request is on http and may be it gets redirected to https when it reaches the server because of app.UseHttpsRedirection().

Comment: No, I don''t use identity server - @nalnpir
I thought of that too, I removed the `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` and the same error appears - @RameshKanjinghat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me several hours later.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I am now only using the `AllowAnyOrigin()`, `AllowAnyHeader()` and the `AllowAnyMethod()`. I assume there was an issue with the `AllowCredentials()`. Hopefully this answer helps someone in the future.